# "Life Beyond Transactions" Entity-Message-Activity Model in Practice?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hbase, riak

Over vacation I read Pat Helland's ["Life Beyond Transactions"](http://blogs.msdn.com/pathelland/archive/2007/05/16/link-to-life-beyond-distributed-transactions-an-apostate-s-opinion.aspx) (yes, vacation was that good :). To sum it up briefly, it advocates limiting the scope of transactions to a single entity and then using groups of "activities" that have the ability to update the entity or cancel a task anytime a change takes place that would make that task invalid.

(E.g. Shipping Order A requires some amount of Item 1. The Shipping Orders and Items are stored as entities and have their own activities. Shipping Order B ships with the last of Item 1 before A finishes. The activity for Item 1 cancels Shipping Order A.)

I had thought I was printing out the Dynamo paper, so forgive me if I conflate the two here. I've seen quite a few "NoSQL" projects influenced by Dynamo and BigTable, particularly in how they address entities by keys and partition data. I was wondering if this Entity-Message-Activity model has influenced any of them?

Or, to put it in more concrete terms, if I have an operation in HBase, Cassandra, Riak, etc. that spans multiple entities, do I need to implement an Activity all by myself (as more of a design pattern in the application), or is there some kind of existing framework? Or do they do something else completely that renders this entire question moot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can add my 2 cents here just from a Cassandra point of view (I haven't used the other NoSQL engines available). Cassandra is primarily designed to be a fast read-write structure. Twitter is a great use case for Cassandra (check the twitter clone [Twissandra](http://twissandra.com/) for this)

Assuming I have understood your question correctly: yes you will have to implement the activity yourself. To understand the modeling of Column/SuperColumnFamilies I would suggest reading this great article [WTF is a SuperColumn?](http://arin.me/blog/wtf-is-a-supercolumn-cassandra-data-model)

Cheers!